# SQL Query for most connected "vertex"

Tags: sql

how does a query for a most connected vertex/tuple look like - who is the actor with the most movies?

for example again the movies and actors sample tables:

```
Movies (moviesID, title)
Actors (actorsID, name)
Relations (moviesID, actorsID)
```

Probably using inner joins? An example would be great - thanks

Comment: What SQL vendor are you using? Oracle, Microsoft, MySQL, Postgre?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 yourID FROM table GROUP BY yourID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Comment: i am using Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `actorsId`, then no joins are necessary:

```
select top 1 actorsId, count(*) as nummovies
from relations r
group by actorsId
order by nummovies desc;
```

Because there might be duplicates, you might want `top 1 with ties`:

```
select top 1 with ties actorsId, count(*) as nummovies
from relations r
group by actorsId
order by nummovies desc;
```

Also, because an actor could have multiple roles in the same movies, if distinct roles are represented in the database, choose `count(distinct)`:

```
select top 1 with ties actorsId, count(distinct moviesId) as nummovies
from relations r
group by actorsId
order by nummovies desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
            A.actorsID, A.name, COUNT(R.moviesID) AS MovieCount
FROM        Actions     A
INNER JOIN  Relations   R       ON A.actorsID = R.actorsID
GRROUP BY   A.actorsID, A.name
ORDER BY    MovieCount DESC
```